# is there a way to insert a list of objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq, insert

here is a situation!

I have made a list of an entity bound model manually. It looks like this,

```
List<myClassName> ClassList = new List<myClassName>();
myClassName Class = new myClassName();// first list item

Class.Name = "name1";
Class.Id = 1;

ClassList.Add(Class);

Class = new myClassName();// Second list item

Class.Name = "name1";
Class.Id = 1;

ClassList.Add(Class)
```

And then i try to insert them to a repository that i have, like :

```
_MyClass.Insert(ClassList);
```

**here is my repository:**

```
private IRepository<myClassName> _MyClass;
```

and i get this error:

> The entity type `myClassName` is not part of the model for the current context.

I guess this is not the way to do it. but if there is any similar way to insert a list together, please help!

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are trying to add entities? try mapping to an internediary class such as a view entity, and then try inserting that, minus the references.

Comment: Could you please supply the implementation of the `Insert` function in your repository?

Comment: @PaulZahra Let me expplain! _MyClass ius a table, i need to add rows to the table. Each variable `Class` should be a row. and `ClassList` will be alist of rows.

Comment: @linkerro It is the basic one. I have not overridden any...!

Comment: @PrashanthBenny : Do you have any unique constraints on your columns? If so, it might let you to add duplicates. Just my two cents.

Comment: @RitwikSen I have an Id as a Primary key auto incremented in the myClassName.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny: If Id is Auto incremented, try not adding the Id value from your code. Merely send over the Name.

Comment: @RitwikSen That was the damn issue...!